# Magento Admin Tool to remove ALL product images

Tags: magento

Is there an admin tool in Magento which will remove all images from all products? I know you can go product-by-product and remove all images, but I'm wondering if there's an admin tool which will do all products at once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14):

I am not sure why you would like to do this but here is a way to do it directly from the Database.

1. Backup then truncate these 2 tables:

   catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
   catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
2. then delete *'/media/catalog/product'*
3. clear all caches.

I haven't tested it but it should do the job. If it doesnt work then restore those 2 tables

Comment: This works perfectly and prevents duplicate images building against products during dev stages. Should be marked as correct answer.

Comment: I kept getting an error while trying to truncate the table.  
#1701 - Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`dbname`.`catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOG_PRODUCT_MEDIA_GALLERY_VALUE_GALLERY` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `dbname`.`catalog_pro)

Comment: I got the foreign key constraint message aswell. I solved it by just deleting all the records with "DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery;" which gives the same result in the end.

Answer (score 3):

This method is tested and does work. One reason you might want to do this is when you're testing Dataflow Import for products. When you specify images in the upload, Magento only *adds* images - it doesn't replace or remove them.

The net result is that several runs of a profile will accumulate a number of images that are superfluous.

```
mysql> **truncate catalog_product_entity_media_gallery;**
mysql> **truncate catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value;**
```

Then, from the command prompt of your Magento media/catalog folder:

```
media/catalog$ **rm -rf ./product/**
```

Comment: This worked for me, although i prefer to cd into the directory itself media/catalog/product/ then rm -rf from inside, just for my own sanity

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to do this via the DB, but if you must:

```
ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` 
 DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID`,
 DROP FOREIGN KEY `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_VAL_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_ID`;

TRUNCATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value`;
TRUNCATE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`;

ALTER TABLE `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` 
 ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_STORE_ID_CORE_STORE_STORE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_VAL_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_MDA_GLR_VAL_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`value_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` (`value_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Then you can delete the product folders with:

```
cd media/catalog/product
rm -rf *
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how I fixed it:

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\Processor $processor
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->product = $product;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->processor = $processor;
    }

    protected function removeImageGallery($product)
    {
        try {
            $gallery = $this->resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery');
            $galleryValue = $this->resource->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value');

            $sql = <<<EOT
DELETE FROM {$gallery}
WHERE value_id IN (SELECT value_id FROM {$galleryValue} WHERE entity_id = {$product->getId()})
EOT;

            $response = $this->resource->getConnection()->query($sql);

            echo '(' . $product->getTypeId() . '): ' . $product->getSku() . " - No. Images: " . $response->rowCount() .  "\n";


//            // Or if you want to try the Magento way
//
//            $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
//            foreach($images as $child){
//                echo '(' . $product->getTypeId() . '): ' . $product->getSku() . ' - ' . $child->getFile() . "\n";
//                $this->processor->removeImage($product, $child->getFile());
//            }
//
//            $this->productRepository->save($product);

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage() . "\n";
        }
    }
```